# What is the best Automation Tool for Testing Native IPhone and Ipad application?

Tags: ipad, unit-testing, automation

I am looking for any Functional Automation testing tool for Testing my native Ipad application,whether its a paid tool or open source, but i am not looking for only record and Play option, the Tool should have option to write the scripts in any programming language, and should generate a Proper results after running the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [UI Automation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW75) documentation.

> The Automation instrument, guided by your test scripts, exercises the
>   user interface elements of your application, allowing you to log the
>   results for your analysis. The Automation feature can simulate many
>   user actions supported by devices that support multitasking and run
>   iOS 4.0 or later. Your test script can run both on the iOS device and
>   in the iOS Simulator without modification.
>
> An important benefit of the Automation instrument is that you can use
>   it with other instruments to perform sophisticated tests such as
>   tracking down memory leaks and isolating causes of performance
>   problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am also doing a similar thing and I found http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-faq 
I am currently trying it out and it seems to be working fine. I was wondering if you found anything else that may be open source? 
Thanks...